Imported Task record not showing as "Call Logged"
I am importing task data manually via data loader And I am expecting it should appear as
"Call Logged". But it is showing as Task created.

Here are my values that I am importing.
Description Subject OwnerId             WhatId              Status      TaskSubType CallType
TEST        Call    0055i0000039dBBAAY  500Ik000001M0BrIAK  Completed   Call        Inbound

Please help to fix this issues.
Thank you
Thiru

Are records created from the UI and via Dataloader completely the same? I would check each field. I'm sure you will find missing piece in the records that is created via Dataloader.

Hi . I have mentioned all the fields I used in the question

As per SF support this current behavior is working as designed.
To improve this functionality in future Salesforce releases, they recommend submitting an idea to the Salesforce Idea Exchange.
